# Why does my code cause a deadlock?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, deadlock

First I want to say that I'm sorry if this is a bad question. I had a question about this issue earlier this morning and could fix some issues, but I'm still getting a deadlock and I'm struggling with this the whole morning.

I'm trying to request chats from a server. In UWP, I need to do this asynchronously. My approach causes a deadlock at about every 5th try I'm running the following code.

The first await happens in `OnNavigatedTo`:

```
public async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    IsLoadMoreItemsPossible = true;
    if (_first)
    {
        _first = false;
        await LoadDataTaskAsync();
    }
}
```

Which calls `LoadDataTaskAsync`:

```
private async Task LoadDataTaskAsync()
{
    if (IsBusy)
    {
        return;
    }

    IsLoadMoreItemsPossible = false;
    IsBusy = true;
    IsFree = false;
    if (!CommonUtils.isInternetAvailable())
    {
        // load from local
    }
    await _remoteDataManager.requestChats();
}
```

`_remoteDataManager.requestChats()` gets the right method for the current platform:

```
public async Task requestChats()
{
    await _websocketManager.requestChats();
}
```

`requestChats` in my UWP WebsocketManager looks like this:

```
public async Task requestChats()
{
    dataWriter.WriteString(WebsocketRequestFactory.Create(SocketEventsEnm.GET_CHATS));
    await SendData(dataWriter);
}
```

And finally `SendData`, where the exception happens:

```
private async Task SendData(DataWriter dataWriter)
{
    try
    {
        _evaLogger.Info("Trying to send data...");
        await dataWriter.StoreAsync(); // This is where the exception occurs
        _evaLogger.Info("Data was sent");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _evaLogger.Error(e.Message, e);
    }
}
```

`_evaLogger` writes into a logfile, which logs this when the deadlock happens:

> 12.12.2016 10:38:08 - Info: Websocket Opened
>
> 12.12.2016 10:38:08 - Info: Trying to send data...
>
> 12.12.2016 10:38:08 - Error: A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)
>
> 12.12.2016 10:38:09 - Info: Trying to send data...
>
> 12.12.2016 10:38:09 - Info: Data was sent

Sorry for the long question, I tried to only show the relevant code for the deadlock.

### EDIT 1:

I tried Azhar Khorasany's suggestion in the comments to use semaphore while accessing the stream:

```
public class AsyncLock
{
    public readonly AsyncSemaphore m_semaphore;
    private readonly Task<Releaser> m_releaser;

    public AsyncLock()
    {
        m_semaphore = new AsyncSemaphore(1);
        m_releaser = Task.FromResult(new Releaser(this));
    }

    public Task<Releaser> LockAsync()
    {
        var wait = m_semaphore.WaitAsync();
        return wait.IsCompleted ?
            m_releaser :
            wait.ContinueWith((_, state) => new Releaser((AsyncLock)state),
                this, CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
}
```

New `requestChats` method:

```
private static readonly AsyncLock m_lock = new AsyncLock();

public async Task requestChats()
{
    using (await m_lock.LockAsync())
    {
        using (DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(messageWebsocket.OutputStream))
        {
            _evaLogger.Info("dataWriter initialized requestChats.");
            dataWriter.WriteString(WebsocketRequestFactory.Create(SocketEventsEnm.GET_CHATS));
            await SendData(dataWriter, "requestChats");
        }
    }
    _evaLogger.Info("dataWriter disposed requestChats.");
}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't solve the deadlock issue:

> 13.12.2016 07:55:31 - Info: Websocket Opened
>
> 13.12.2016 07:55:32 - Info: dataWriter initialized requestChats.
>
> 13.12.2016 07:55:32 - Info: Trying to send data... requestChats
>
> 13.12.2016 07:55:32 - Error: A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)
>
> 13.12.2016 07:55:32 - Info: dataWriter disposed requestChats.
>
> 13.12.2016 07:55:32 - Info: Trying to send data... requestContacts
>
> 13.12.2016 07:55:32 - Info: dataWriter initialized requestContacts.

Comment: the `0x8000000E` error means that your asynchronous operation did not finished but you tried to get the result.

Comment: Is it that you are trying to Store/Write to a stream and multiple threads are accessing the same stream. You need to put a semaphore around: await dataWriter.StoreAsync();

Comment: @AzharKhorasany Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it didn't solve the issue. I've edited my question

Comment: @AzharKhorasany actually I see that I did a mistake, I should use the semaphore in `requestChats` already... Sorry, trying that out now

Comment: @AzharKhorasany Didn't solve the issue :( Edited question again (see bottom)

Comment: Where is your dataWriter instantiated? Can't you instantiate it within the SendData() method? DataWriter should not be shared. It should instantiate, do its job and be disposed.

Comment: @AzharKhorasany that makes sense, I will try it. Even if that won't be the issue here, I already learned a lot now. Thanks!

Comment: @AzharKhorasany Doing it this way (instantiating, doing it's job, disposing) would make the semaphore not necessary in my case then, right?

Comment: You still need a lock because otherwise several threads might try to connect to one socket and may fail. Socket is a dependency in your program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130472/discussion-between-zure-and-azhar-khorasany).

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential problems in this code because it's clearly not written with parallel threads in mind. What your immediate problem is, as far as I can tell from your code, is that `dataWriter` shared among the threads. Imagine that one thread may be executing `dataWriter.WriteString(...)` while another thread is executing `dataWriter.StoreAsync()` and you see the problem. You need to read up about parallel programming and have a full understanding of how you code executes. Having flags like `IsBusy` may "work" in a one-thread-program it is bound to cause you headaches as soon as you have multiple threads.

Quick advice to your code:
Remove your global declaradion of `dataWriter` and change the following code:

```
public async Task requestChats()
{
    /* declare dataWriter here so it becomes an instance variable*/
    dataWriter.WriteString(WebsocketRequestFactory.Create(SocketEventsEnm.GET_CHATS));
await SendData(dataWriter);
```

Comment: The problem is that the `IsBusy` flags are not my code, so I don't really want to change that unless it is really necessary. I'm trying to clean my dataWriter stuff now and then see if it works. Thanks